# How to get all rows from a table to an android app

Tags: java, android, sql

my problem is i can't get all rows in a table to my android app my table is in a ms sql database and i want to get all the columns into a textview when i try to get them it only gets the first row in my table any help?

here is my code:

```
public class words extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,rr,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,z1,z2;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    ProgressBar loading;
    private TextView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.أ);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ب);
        c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ت);
        d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ث);
        e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        f = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        g = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        h = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        i = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        j = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);
        k = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
        l = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
        m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button26);
        n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
        o = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
        p = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24);
        q = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button20);
        rr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button27);
        s = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button29);
        t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button28);
        u = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button31);
        v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button30);
        w = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button32);
        x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button33);
        y = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button34);
        z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button35);
        z1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button36);
        z2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button37);
        loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);

        DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin(); // this is the Asynctask
        doLogin.execute("");




    }
    public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String message = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;








        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(words.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isSuccess) {
                Toast.makeText(words.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                        if (con == null) {
                            message = "Error in connection with SQL server please contact the administrator";
                        } else {

                            String query = "SELECT * FROM country INNER JOIN family ON country.CID = family.CID";
                            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);





                            if(rs.next())
                            {
                                try {
                                    String theword =  (rs.getString("FName"));

                                    if (theword.contains("أ")){

                                        a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ب")){

                                        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ت")){

                                        c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ث")){

                                        d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ج")){

                                        e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    } else if (theword.contains("ح")){

                                        f.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("خ")){

                                        g.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("د")){

                                        h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ذ")){

                                        i.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ر")){

                                        j.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ز")){

                                        k.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("س")){

                                        l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ش")){

                                        m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ص")){

                                        n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ض")){

                                        o.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ط")){

                                        p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ظ")){

                                        q.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ع")){

                                        rr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("غ")){

                                        s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ف")){

                                        t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ق")){

                                        u.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ك")){

                                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ل")){

                                        w.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("م")){

                                        x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ن")){

                                        y.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ه")){

                                        z.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("و")){

                                        z1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ي")){

                                        z2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else {
                                        message ="WERE IS THE FWORD COLUMN?!?!";
                                    }


                                    isSuccess=true;
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    message = "Exception e = "+e;
                                    isSuccess = false;
                                }





                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        isSuccess = false;
                        message = "Exceptions"+ex;

                    }


                }
            });

            return message;
            }
        }

    }
```

with this code it always give me in my text view only one row

any help?!

**EDIT:**

THE QUERY RETURNS ALL ROWS SUCCESSFULLY BUT IT DOESN'T DO THE SAME THING IN THE APP

***SOLVED***

I replaced  if(rs.next()) with  while(rs.next()) and it solved my problem!

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM country INNER JOIN family ON country.CID = family.CID` returns all rows you want to?

Comment: it only returns one row but how can i make it return all of the rows

Comment: When you use `INNER JOIN` search for all occurrences and if it finds any null or empty value does not returned, try to use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: do you mean that my code have to return all rows but i have to use 'LEFT JOIN' rather than 'INNER JOIN'

Comment: Yes, please refer to this [link](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types).

Comment: @Francisco Sevilla that didn't really solve my problem,first of all my table doesn't contain any nulls,second thing that i want my app to get all the rows of a column in a table.

Comment: have you tried changing if(rs.next()) to while(re.next()) ?? cause i'm seeing that 'if statement' can never be a loop by itself

Comment: can you run your query directly on SQL Server? Using Management Studio or some other query tool? The question is, does this query even return more than one row to begin with... just to confirm. It's a good thing to check.

Comment: it returns successfully all rows!

Answer (score 0):

First ensure your query is returning more than 1 row, execute it using any tool for that,

```
SELECT column_name
FROM country 
INNER JOIN family 
ON country.CID = family.CID
```

If not, the issue comes with your `INNER JOIN` and change it to `LEFT JOIN` to return even the null values if that the case.

Select the `column_name` directly to avoid retrieve all columns you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possibilities for your issue,

1. Your selection query `"SELECT * FROM country INNER JOIN family ON country.CID = family.CID"` might be returning just a single row, verify that it returns all the required rows. To verify that the total number of rows are available, you can attach a break-point at this line `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`  and evaluate the left-hand side of the statement.
2. Even if assumed, that your selection query is working fine and returning all the expected rows. You need to iterate over the results( as suggested by @Psycho ) to fetch all rows from your query results.

As the docs say:

---

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of
>   data. Initially, the cursor is positioned before the first row. The
>   next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns
>   false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be
>   used in a while loop to iterate through the result set. A default
>   ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward
>   only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the
>   first row to the last row.

---

So what you can do is this,

```
    if(rs.first()) //move the cusor to first position              
{
               do{
                                try {
                                    String theword =  (rs.getString("FName"));

                                    if (theword.contains("أ")){

                                        a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ب")){

                                        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ت")){

                                        c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ث")){

                                        d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ج")){

                                        e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    } else if (theword.contains("ح")){

                                        f.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("خ")){

                                        g.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("د")){

                                        h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ذ")){

                                        i.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ر")){

                                        j.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ز")){

                                        k.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("س")){

                                        l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ش")){

                                        m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ص")){

                                        n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ض")){

                                        o.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ط")){

                                        p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ظ")){

                                        q.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ع")){

                                        rr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("غ")){

                                        s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ف")){

                                        t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ق")){

                                        u.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ك")){

                                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ل")){

                                        w.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("م")){

                                        x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ن")){

                                        y.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ه")){

                                        z.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("و")){

                                        z1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else if (theword.contains("ي")){

                                        z2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }else {
                                        message ="WERE IS THE FWORD COLUMN?!?!";
                                    }


                                    isSuccess=true;
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    message = "Exception e = "+e;
                                    isSuccess = false;
                                }

         }  while(rs.next()); //iterate till the next row is available  




                            }
```

Comment: i have just tried it but it didn't work and am sure my query returns all data please help!